# Can DC voltage be stepped-up to electric motor requirements in an electric car?

Tags: batteries

why is necessary to place 100 or so cell stacks in series to obtain the ~400V of an electric car such as the Model S instead of limiting the series arrangement to a much lower voltage and stepping it up the requirements of the electric motor?

if i understand transformers correctly the power (voltage x current) stays the same when the voltage is stepped up or down based on the number of windings in a transformer.

Comment: Transformers don't work on DC.  You would have to convert the battery voltage to an AC signal, step it up with a transformer, and then convert the stepped up AC voltage to DC.  This would add considerably to the electronics package in size and cost and impact on efficiency and reliability.

Comment: Can you either post a circuit diagram or hint at a link that substantiates what you say in your question. At the moment your question is: "Can DC voltage be stepped-up to electric motor requirements in an electric car?" and the answer is clearly a BIG YES.

Comment: sorry, i dont know anything about circuit diagrams. im a chemist. the reason i ask is the following. cells in series require balancing circuit boards and wiring while those in parallel do not. what is the reason for which the number of cells in series is not reduced by stepping up the voltage? also, does the (induction) motor have a voltage requirement of a power requirement? why is 400V used?

Answer (score 4):

As you say the power remains the same (approximately) for stepping up a voltage using a transformer. So to get a higher voltage you need to draw proportionally more current. Drawing more current from a battery is not free, they have internal impedance which [limits the amount you can draw](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/112144/15805). You can rest assured that electric vehicle engineers have considered this and have optimized the power system for efficiency.

Besides that you're trading battery mass for transformer mass, and transformers don't bring energy to the system.

Comment: ah. very good point. this actually encourages me. i have been working on a lithium/sulfur battery for a few years. this is a 2V battery with very large capacity >800 mAh/g depending on how i prepare the cathode. i read on battery pack balancing and it seems cells in series require additional weight in terms of BMS circuit boards, while cells in parallel do not, yielding a disadvantage to increasing the number of cells in series. so in the the case of this battery, additional current is not a issue. would this approach of stepping up voltage work well in this case in your opinion?

Comment: @guywithaquestion I would think BMS boards add grams to the system, so not a large disadvantage. While the high current system would require much more metal to reduce the I^2R losses, even assuming the battery is not limited. I'm guessing the trade off is in favor of more BMS subcircuits.

Comment: i see. however keep i mind each 18650 cell the model s is using weighs only ~45 grams

Comment: im confused about @Samuel main response however: "So to get a higher voltage you need to draw proportionally more current. Drawing more current from a battery is not free, ..." the higher current would not be the result of discharging the same number of cells in parallel at higher rates, BUT it would be the result of discharging a higher number of batteries in parallel at the same (or lower) rate. this would not change the internal impedance of each cell.

Comment: @guywithaquestion It's not per cell, a *battery* is multiple cells. You need to maintain the same amount of power, if you're going to do that with a battery (multiple cells connected) at a lower voltage, you must draw more current.

Comment: lets say 10 Li-NCA, 3.4 Ah cells are arranged such that 5 "bricks", each composed of 2 cells in parallel are stacked in series. The voltage of the pack is 5x3.9V~20V. the current of the battery pack is given only by the total current flowing through the bricks however. if we discharge the bricks at C/5 we get a current of (3.4Ax2)/5)=~1.4A and a power of 1.4Ax20V=28W.

Comment: if we increase the brick size to 5 cells each and reduce the stack to 2 bricks in series we will have a total voltage of ~8V and to maintain the same power, we need to flow 28W/8V=3.5A which we can obtain by discharging each of the 5 cells in parallel from a brick at a rate of C/5 or (3.4Ax5)/5~3.5A. according to the above, individual cells discharge at the same rate in either scenario. more current is flown in the second scenario due to 5 cells in parallel instead of 2 but the impedance in each cell in parallel is the same in either scenario as well. am i right?

Comment: @guywithaquestion Again, I'm not talking about per cell current. I'm talking about *battery* current. Which you just demonstrated is higher to to get the same power from a lower voltage battery.

Answer (score 4):

Consider that a transformer steps the voltage up or down by having different numbers of turns on its primary and secondary windings - to step up, use fewer turns of thicker wire (because it has to carry more current) on the primary, and more turns of thinner wire on the secondary.

If that was all there was to powering an electric car, you could throw away the transformer altogether and rewind the motor with fewer turns of thicker wire. (And in model RC cars, people tune the performance by selecting the motor winding turns). After all, why add weight to a sports car?

So there's more to it. With the batteries we have now, it's more efficient to use relatively high voltages from many cells in series), rather than insanely high currents (many cells in parallel) and much thicker and heavier wire.

Comment: i cannot judge the validity of "you could throw away the transformer altogether and rewind the motor with fewer turns of thicker wire." i am a chemist. but its an interesting point. why do you say "With the batteries we have now, it's more efficient to use relatively high voltages from many cells in series), rather than insanely high currents (many cells in parallel) and much thicker and heavier wire."? please explain it sounds interesting.

Comment: If nothing else, it's a small scale version of the economics of the grid. To transmit higher voltage, even from battery to motor, is relatively cheap : to transmit higher current you would need lower resistance wiring, and that means more raw materials (copper isn't cheap!) as well as more weight, which is undesirable in a car. (In the motor itself, you end up with the same mass of copper either way.) You might make aluminium wiring work, but oxidation, corrosion and fire risk pose problems you'd have to solve. See also Samuel's point about internal resistance, or power lost in the batteries.

Comment: i understand your argument. is the 400V then just a function of cost and not of motor requirement? why not use double or triple the voltage then and limit the current passed even more.

Comment: Look at the price of 1000+V semiconductors! Or multi-thousand amp ones for that matter. And at some voltage the insulation requirements would start getting more difficult. There might be quite a broad minimum in the cost/voltage curve, perhaps around 200-500V, but it's a minimum and that's what matters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the batteries are simply connected in series. There was something on the Tesla web site that indicated that the inverter in the Roadster used 72 IGBT transistors. That indicates to me that a multilevel inverter is used. That would allow the inverter to produce a high quality waveform without much filtering. A lot of information that is available about Tesla indicates that they have put a lot of effort into developing a very efficient design and do not limit themselves to design approaches that are widely used.

Comment: yes, the model S motor has an inverter according to teslamotorsclub. this is maybe how they control the torque on the induction motor.